# Count Ids according to occurrences from different columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with two columns `MentionedUserIds` (`nvarchar`) and `CreatedUserId` (`int`).

I would like to count the occurrences of each of the users.

```
Id MentionedUserId CreatorUserId
--------------------------------
1    10,11,12,13     4
2    10,13,15,4      5
```

I need the result like this:

```
UserId MentionedUserCount CreatorUserCount
-------------------------------------------
 4        1                  1
 5        0                  1
10        2                  0 
11        1                  0 
12        1                  0
13        2                  0 
15        1                  0
```

The users are stored in a different table.

Comment: **Tip:** do **NOT** store multiple values in a single column - this is a **horribly bad design** and violates even the first normal form of database design. Use proper relational constructs and store *at most ONE* value per column.

Comment: Why `UserId` `12` is `0` in `MentionedUserCount`?

Comment: Sorry, it should be 1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question is trivial once the data is normalized. This can be done through any number of [functions or tricks](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).

With Microsoft Full-Text Search available:

```
With Src As (
    Select * From (Values 
        (1, '10,11,12,13', 4),
        (2, '10,13,15,4' , 5)
    ) V (Id, MentionedUserId, CreatorUserId)
), Normalised As (
    Select CreatorUserId, CAST(display_term AS int) As MentionedUserId
    From Src
    Cross Apply (
        Select display_term
        From sys.dm_fts_parser('"' + MentionedUserId + '"', 1033, 0, 0)
        Where display_term NOT Like 'nn%'
    ) Split
), UserList As (
    Select CreatorUserId As UserId From Normalised Union
    Select MentionedUserId         From Normalised
)
Select UserId,
    (Select Count(*) From Normalised Where MentionedUserId = UserId) As MentionedUserCount,
    (Select Count(*) From Src        Where CreatorUserId   = UserId) As CreatorUserCount
From UserList;
```

Through XML trick:

```
With Src As (
    Select * From (Values 
        (1, '10,11,12,13', 4),
        (2, '10,13,15,4' , 5)
    ) V (Id, MentionedUserId, CreatorUserId)
), Normalised As (
    Select CreatorUserId, y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'int') As MentionedUserId
    From Src
    Cross Apply (Select CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(MentionedUserId, ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>').query('.') As x) As a
    Cross Apply x.nodes('i') As y(i)
), UserList As (
    Select CreatorUserId As UserId From Normalised Union
    Select MentionedUserId         From Normalised
)
Select UserId,
    (Select Count(*) From Normalised Where MentionedUserId = UserId) As MentionedUserCount,
    (Select Count(*) From Src        Where CreatorUserId   = UserId) As CreatorUserCount
From UserList;
```